# Transform a hyperlink from user (in text) to image

Tags: javascript, html, image, chat

What do I have to do in JavaScript when a user gives a comment and in that comment there is a image link (*.jpg or *.png) and I want to check realtime to make that source an image tag with javascript. How do I do this check?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a expression to check the file extension:

```
function checkURL(url) {
    return(url.match(/\.(jpeg|jpg|gif|png)$/) != null);
}
```

Check to see if an image can load the URL by using a function like this:

```
function testImage(url, callback, timeout) {
    timeout = timeout || 5000;
    var timedOut = false, timer;
    var img = new Image();
    img.onerror = img.onabort = function() {
        if (!timedOut) {
            clearTimeout(timer);
            callback(url, "error");
        }
    };
    img.onload = function() {
        if (!timedOut) {
            clearTimeout(timer);
            callback(url, "success");
        }
    };
    img.src = url;
    timer = setTimeout(function() {
        timedOut = true;
        callback(url, "timeout");
    }, timeout); 
}
```

This function will call your callback at some future time with two arguments: the original URL and a result ("success", "error" or "timeout").